# Update router firmware without using web interface

Tags: wireless-router, firmware

I have a `D-Link DSL-2740EL` wireless router. How can i update router's firmware without using web interface ?

Assume router's firmware is corrupted. so i can't log in to my router. then how can i update firmware ?

Is there any other method to update firmware without using web interface ?

Comment: Have you tried the reset process? Press and hold `reset` for 10 seconds.

Comment: yes. also tried process in [here](http://forums.dlink.com/index.php?topic=44909.0). but not worked.

Comment: Also, it may be worth a try to use the [recover from a bad flash](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Recover_from_a_Bad_Flash) instructions for dd-wrt

Comment: tried this also. but not worked.

Comment: What's the warranty on it? If the firmware is corrupt and it's the stock, approved, firmware, it should be covered. Or it's not the firmware, it's the hardware.

Comment: You don't have a great deal of choices since the firmware is corrupt so in alternatives to logging into the mini-hTTP server is out of the question.  You would have to hope there is a JTAG port and have the technical expertise to do it that way, but thats only a possible fix, not a guarantee fix if say the router uses a protected firmware.

Comment: @Ramhound can i use a flash tool and install the firmware ? if i can, can you refer some flash tool to do that.

Comment: @Bishan - Those tools are useless when the router is bricked. Because of the age of the router you might be just better of getting a new one.  The router doesn't even have a JTAG port so even that isn't an option.